# In Google Chrome some web pages, the font changes for no apparent reason

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts

I found this bug in Google Chrome that I cannot explain.

The fonts that is loaded for a text sometimes changes for some reason by itself.

Here is a screenshot of the initial font when the web page loads:

[image: The initial font]

Here is what I see after a while:

[image: What shows up after a while]

When I start scrolling on the page the font returns to normal.

Does anybody knows what is going on?

Also I have seen this happening on many other websites. And even on my own web pages.

I am using Google Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57, and I am on a Mac OS X 10.9.

The screenshot come from the DropBox documentation web site.

Comment: Yup, I get this too.  I assume this is just a bug in Chrome, as it didn't use to happen.

Comment: I also am fed up with this bug and decided to research it. It's not an easy thing to Google. Perhaps most people just don't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known Chrome bug and will supposedly be fixed in Chrome 33: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298